# Tool that shows file/line/function of each malloc request and release

Tags: library, c++, c, memory-management

Recently I got a simple memory check tool that uses preload to hack all memory requests and releases.
But currently only collects pointer addresses and size that have not been released. Is there any way to get more caller information? Like **FILE**,**LINE** or **FUNCTION**.
The goal is to use the tool without modifying and compiling the target program.